# Get app service name in azure programmatically

Tags: azure

Simple question, hopefully a simple answer :)

How to I get the app service name, displayed as "test-webapp" in the picture below, from code (C#)?  (any other identifier of a specific app service also works).

I have multiple app services, running same code. So I want to be able to express

```
if(appServiceName == "test-webapp")
{
    //take a specific value from web.config and run with it
}
```

[image: see image]

Answer (score 9):

You can get it from the `WEBSITE_SITE_NAME` environment variable.

To get the variable, use something like:

```
string siteName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_SITE_NAME")
```

You can see a list of environment variables available here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment.

Comment: Ok, they will be hosted on the same web site url, with load balancing, but Ill have a verify when I can get some code out. Thanks for your tips!

Comment: Though an alternative approach might be to override settings in web.config via Application Settings. Have you considered that?

Comment: Thats a good idea! I will look into that if plan A does not work out. Thanks again :)